# Where to send Portugal Appeal documents?

Tags: visa-refusals, portugal

I have been rejected for a Portuguese Visitor visa and they gave me right to an appeal. On the refusal they did not mention any email or address for the appeal post. I am a well settled person in the UK, I sent them my personal and business bank statements along with all supporting documents like hotel and air booking, but they said they did not understand my purpose of travel.

It seems like the visa officer did not see my all supporting documents. So I have to appeal now, which I have ready with more explanation but don't know where to send it?

Please help if any one knows about their address or email in UK.

Answer (score 1):

The Schengen Visa Code (12.3) states that when notifying the refusal to the applicant, information regarding the procedure to be followed in the event of an appeal should be given
https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf#77

If there’s really no information or address for appeal given in the refusal letter, I would write to the Portuguese Consulate nearest to where you live. Addresses are available here:
https://www.londres.embaixadaportugal.mne.pt/en/consular-services/general-information

See this question [Schengen tourist visa refused. Can I appeal for reconsideration?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20849/schengen-tourist-visa-refused-can-i-appeal-for-reconsideration) for advice on what your appeal letter should contain.

Comment: The OP could also attach to the question an image of the refusal letter, with personal information blacked out, so we can look at it. Given the clarity of the Schengen Visa Code, it seems likely that this information was included in the letter.